# Emacs eventually stops opening new files after running for a while and has to be restarted

Tags: macos, emacs

On osx with emacs 24 (installed via macports) I use the code below to make sure all files opened in emacs are opened in one new window, this functionality is essential for my emacs usage.

```
(setq ns-pop-up-frames nil)
```

This works well at first, but eventually, without exceptions, emacs will start failing to open files at the first try and require repeated action to open it (ie. double clicking twice, or selecting a file twice in an app).

This has been the case when I installed emacs from a different source and through several versions of osx. As a way to see if `(ns-pop-up-frames nil)` creates some kind of issue I'd like to try another way to use emacs in the same way (all files opened in a new buffer), but I'm not sure how to do that. Also, could it be that something else is the problem?

Comment: Please further explain what you mean by:  "(ie. double clicking twice, or selecting a file twice in an app)"  Are you trying to launch files using the Finder.app or some other unspecified application that is not Emacs?  Have you tried a nightly build from http://emacsformacosx.com/ so you can take advantage of the master branch?   Are you running a daemon of Emacs and playing around with emacsclient?

Comment: I mean finder as well as opening from alfred (app/file launcher). I don't see anything related to a daemon or emacsclient in my .emacs. Just the (setq ... nil) stuff quoted above.

Comment: I have not tried the nightly build, maybe I will but I'm worried it may be a bit too unstable.